# How to Implement Role based Menu Access List in WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, menu, user-roles

I am in the phase of designing Role based access list in which the Roles will be assigned to Groups rather to individual users, please see the screen shot of excel file for full Idea of tables.

There are 6 Tables.

User, Group, UserGroup, Role, GroupRole, Menu

UserGroup (Many to Many between User and Group)
GroupRole (Many to Many between Role and Group)

Now what I want to is based on the Group I want to implement the Menu and fetch its menu items and populate my Navigation Bar Items. The Menu table is also visible in the screen shot.

I need experts advice on how to achieve the linking of Menu with the Group, I think the Menu should have a link with Group with (Many to Many )but I need your advice here.

Result:
At the end what I want is that when a user will login based on his Group his menu will be populated in our WPF application and then based on his roles he will able to use the application.

Please guide if I am not on the right track.
[image]

Comment: I think to start this off you will need a link table between menu and probably roles to determine which roles can view which menu items

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement properties/methods that evaluate permissions of the current user (e.g. CurrentUser.AllowedToCreate, CurrentUser.AllowedToRead, ...). To reduce the number of permissions you might use enum flags (AllowedToCreate = AllowedToRead + AllowedToCreate).

Then on the WPF side you can control the Visibility/IsEnabled of the menu items by DataTriggers (MultipleDataTriggers).

Comment: I am first trying to design the database so I appreciate youe suggestion first in aligning the tables. So what you suggest, shall attach my Menu table with Role Table using Many to Many or shall I attach Menu table with Group Table using Many to Many, bit confused

Comment: For example if I'm a manager and all users in group Managers might read and update Sales, then you need to create many-to-many table MenuGroupRole that has MenuId and GrouRoleId and add then two rows in it (Sales,Managers,Read and Sales,Manager,Update).

Comment: awesome, so if I am understanding correctly I will create the many to many relation between Menu table and GroupRole table (MenuGroupRole) and this table will give me all the menus assigned to a GroupRole which eventually will tie up with user because the user will be part of that group. right?